# Is it possible to find $\eta>0$ such that $\forall x\in (\alpha-\eta,\alpha+\eta),\qquad \dfrac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}<1$

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

> Let $I$ an open interval and  $f\in\mathcal{C}^2(I)$, assume that $\alpha\in I$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$ and $f'(\alpha)\ne0$
>
> Is it possible to find $\eta>0$ such that $\forall x\in (\alpha-\eta,\alpha+\eta),\qquad \dfrac{f''(x)}{2f'(x)}<1$

Comment: Why would you think so? You've no information about the second derivative, so it could be very large at a simple root of $f$.Look for a polynomial of high degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No : if you take for exemple $f(x)=\exp(x)-\exp(\alpha)$ for your title, and  $f(x)=\exp(2x)-\exp(2\alpha)$ for your inside text. You will have for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, respectively $f''(x)/f'(x)=1$ and $f''(x)/(2f'(x))=1$.

Comment: One more thing I'm trying to prove now $$\exists \eta >0 ,\forall x\in (\alpha-\eta,\alpha+\eta),\qquad \dfrac{f''(x)}{2f'(x)}\le1$$, but I'm struggling.

Comment: With $f(x)=\exp(\lambda x)-\exp(\lambda \alpha)$ you will have for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,  $f''(x)/2f'(x)=\frac{\lambda}{2}$ ... so with $\lambda>2$,  $f''(x)/2f'(x)>1$, so you can't prove either this statement : it is false in general.